# How to get maximum value where two shapefiles overlap using ArcGIS for Desktop 10.1?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, shapefile

I'm trying to merge 2 datasets (both shapefiles, but I can convert them to raster layers if necessary) where the values are compared, and whichever is higher becomes the new value for the layer. How would I got about this? They aren't quite adjacent to one another, because there's a fairly large overlap in the middle. I'm using ArcMap 10.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do this you would first **[Union](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000s000000)** (keep all fields) the two shapefiles together and add a numeric field called say **MaxValue**.

Then, assuming you have values from **shapefile1** and **shapefile2** called **val1** and **val2** respectively you can use the **[Calculate Field](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000004m000000)** tool with the settings below to calculate **MaxValue**:

Parser:

```
Python
```

Expression:

```
Reclass(!val1!,!val2!)
```

Code Block:

```
def Reclass(val1,val2):
  if (val1 >= val2):
    return val1
  else:
    return val2
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Because I needed to convert them into raster files anyway, I did that, and further down the line I simply used cell statistics with the MAXIMUM function to merge the 2 layers.

Comment: Your code block appears to implement the built-in [max](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) function.